# Create the "frozen window" effect

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

You know when you have a window that is frozen, but when you drag another window over the top it leaves a trail?  Sometimes it looks a little bit like the end of Solitaire for Windows 3 :) when you get done (like my screenshot).

I'd like to make a C# windows (winforms/wpf) application that creates a surface like this and allows me to capture the image, but I'm a little bit at a loss of where to start.

Picture:
[image: Almost looks like Solitaire]

Comment: Stop clearing your screen buffer when you draw the new positions.

Comment: Easiest method is to just run Windows. It'll inevitably happen at some point.

Comment: Instantiate a ton of windows XD

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @HighCore - This is a for fun thing.  I like the effect it makes and want to figure out a way to duplicate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier with **WPF**. You can create a `VisualBrush` from any control, including a `Window` or `FrameworkElement`. Once you have that `VisualBrush`, you can paint it all over your form and it will create that same effect. Alternatively, you could use an `ImageBrush` if you want to do it with a picture rather than a UI element.

When you paint, just offset it by a couple X/Y each time and it will look just like that as it overwrites (er.. overpaints?) itself!

You can create your own class `FrozenVisualHost` that derives from `FrameworkElement` to host a `DrawingVisual` that you render. See: [MSDN: Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx)

Overriding your `FrozenVisualHost.OnRender()` method would allow you to draw your 'frozen snapshots' as you recorded mouse movement (via `MouseMove`). Just make sure that you call the `InvalidateVisual()` method to update the host control.

One caveat: Creating a `VisualBrush` from a window **will not** capture the title bar or window border chrome. If you want that, you'll have to grab a snapshot manually (GDI): [As described here](http://blog.developers.ba/post/2009/09/03/Screenshot-your-WPF-application.aspx). You can use that `Bitmap` however for your `ImageBrush` and do rendering similarly.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I could hook it up to the mouse movement and have it paint on an interval to try and get the same speed based effect (the faster you move on the real frozen window, the more of the original window appears, the slower you move the better chance you have of getting just a solid color, etc...)

Comment: That is actually pretty clever. I was going to write an answer regarding the actual effect, using the classical Windows message loop with manual (and faulty) window drawing, but this... I like this so much more :)